# Add Reference from one QT Project to another in QT?

Tags: qt

how to Add Reference from one QT Project to another in QT ?

I have two QT Projects now i want to add Reference of one form from second project to the first one.
The functionality is like in first project i have one main form which contains two buttons on click of second button second project has got some form that should open.

How to achieve that ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean one of your executable made with Qt should open an other executable made with Qt ? Or are you talking about Qt projects like .pro that are in some way dependent ?

Comment: @Vrince : Ya the first one,one of your executable made with Qt should open an other executable made with Qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused about your question but [QProcess](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html) can be used to start another process and communicate with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
debug:LIBS += -L"../path/to/lib"
release:LIBS += -L"../path/to/lib"
LIBS += -lname
```

You should add this kind of references to .pro file of main project.